# SOQL queries Where Clause given Error UNEXPECTED Token

Tags: apex, soql, query

```
[ SELECT Name, 
  (SELECT Communication_Type__c, Communication_Mode__c, 
          Additional_Information__c, CBProgramInformation__r,  
          Reporting_Type__c FROM Reporting_Detail__c ) 
  FROM CbProgramInformation__c 
  WHERE Name=CBProgramInformation__r ];
```

I made the lookup relation in Reporting Detail Table of `CbProgramInformation`

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Are you using this SOQL in Apex?

Comment: yes I Want to render data in Custom UI using above Where condition. I want to know How I Provide where condition here to render data in Custom UI so I don't get every record

Answer (score 1):

In SOQL and SOSL, we cannot compare 2 fields to one another, so `Name = CBProgramInformation__r` is invalid syntax.

Beyond that, both instances you have of `CBProgramInformation__r` are incorrect. The `__r` form of a field name means that you're traversing a relationship (usually upwards), and must be followed by `.<field name here>` e.g. `My_Custom_Lookup__r.Name`. It can't appear on its own in the SELECT or WHERE clauses.

We also cannot use data from a parent-child subquery (a nested query in the `SELECT` clause) elsewhere in the query.

`CBProgramInformation__c` contains the Id of the related record. Salesforce shows us the record name in the UI, but that's merely a UI quality-of-life thing.

That aside, you haven't provided enough information or context for us to know exactly what you're trying to accomplish by running this query. My best guess here is that you should be able to accomplish what you want by flipping the query around. Instead of querying on `CBProgramInformation__c`, query on `Reporting_Detail__c` and pull the name through the relationship field.

```
[SELECT 
    Communication_Type__c, Communication_Mode__c, 
    Additional_Information__c, CBProgramInformation__r.Name,  
    Reporting_Type__c 
 FROM Reporting_Detail__c
 WHERE <some filters here>
]
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for Answer and Sorry for not clarify the question Basically I Want to render data in Custom UI using above Where condition. Your query is working fine But I want to know How I Provide condition here to render data in Custom UI so I don't get every record